# Vba code to control Edge in IE Mode using iedriverserver.exe

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer

Is there any code sample which I could refer ? To control Edge in IE Mode using iedriverserver.exe in vba. I have downloaded the exe but unable to add related library in tools->reference in vba project.

Please let me know if anyone has knowledge on this topic.Thanks.

Comment: Edge is another structure, IE Mode is not the same as being Internet Explorer, you need [selenium](https://www.guru99.com/excel-vba-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to automate Edge IE mode in VBA at present.

If you want to automate Edge IE mode, you can use Selenium. For more information about using IE driver to automate IE mode in Edge, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp).

Comment: Hi @Neelam I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.